# Django - how to properly construct a json object to be displayed in a Form

Tags: django, python-2.7

In my Django View, I get data from a REST call, which looks like this:

```
{"id":3,"name":"MySQL","description":"MySQL Database Server - Fedora 21 - medium","image":"","flavor":""}
```

When I try to pass it as-is to my Form, I get this error:

data = self.form.initial.get(self.name, self.field.initial)
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'

What is the proper way to "package" such data for a Form?

Answer (score 0):

That response from REST call it is JSON, you need to convert to a python dict.

```
import json
data_dict = json.loads(response)[0]
```

Then you can use your `data_dict` as normal python dict.